# Can Hibernate change structure but keep data?

Tags: java, hibernate, ddl

If I add fields to classes and set

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

will Hibernate add field to table with keeping table's data?

Comment: If you update the entity by adding a field it will be reflect in table without affecting the previous changes, similarly if you delete an field in entity it will not reflect in the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>` : This will update your db schema without losing your data if you are going to add new columns. But if you change definition of any existing column, then it may loose data.